# Java Loop Error

Tags: java

Hi i'm running a simple loop that is supposed to output the numbers 0-10, however when the program is run, nothing appears in the output box, yet the program doesn't throw any errors. Here is the loop:

```
for(int num = 0; num <= 10; num++){
        System.out.println("num = " + num);
    }
```

Comment: What is the issue? Can you include more code?

Comment: doesn't work **HOW**? and this java, not python. indentation doesn't matter.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: The syntax of the loop you provided looks fine. Does your code compile correctly? What is the expected output?

Comment: I was trying to get my program to print the numbers from 1-9 and then stop at 10

Comment: If you only want to print number up to 9 you have to use _ num < 10 _ - you wrote it that the loop runs up to include 10

Answer (score 3):

you should look at some basic java tutorials...

<= is the less than or equal to sign, so your loop will go up to 10.

```
for(int num=1; num<10; num++){
   //some code
}
```

Here, we have a less than to sign, so the loop will keep on going as long as num is LESS then 10.

You could also use this code...

```
for(int num=1; num<=9; num++){
    //some code
}
```

In this case, you're saying keep on going as long as num is less then or equal to 9.

Also, note how I replaced int num=0 with int num=1. Your starting number does not have to be 0.

EDIT:

Well then, I just did a bit of googling and found...

> Where does System.out and System.err output go?
>
> Most of the time, the answer is nowhere
>
> By: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_does_System.out_and_System.err_output_go%3F

Personally I haven't used eclipse, I've only used the command line. There are a few suggestions on that small page so you should take a moment to read it.

You could try doing this simple project in command line first. If you have the java development kit (I believe it was called), all you need to do is use the javac and java commands in command line. This is very basic things, you should be able to google a basic tutorial about running java programs from command line.

Comment: Agreed, this is some basic syntax to pretty much all programming syntax.

Comment: Alright I knew that I just made a mistake; that doesn't answer why nothing is printed once the code is processed Tyler

Comment: hmmm I don't see anything wrong with it... is it compiling fine?

Comment: @NeilKumar Are you sure that the code is getting executed properly? Are you running this in an IDE or from command line?

Comment: Yes the code seems to be compiling fine and I have tweaked the code after seeing your helpful answer, however the list of numbers isn't being printed - this is running in eclipse

Comment: @Neil Kumar  See the edit :P

Answer (score 3):

Since the OP clarified in comment that the intention was to only print the numbers 1-9:

You start the loop with `num = 0`. This means that it will also start by printing a `0`. If it is supposed to print `1` as the first number, the loop should start with `for(int num = 1;`.

Also, as @Gersee wrote in comment, the condition of the loop should be `num < 10` if the intention is to print `9` as the last number. The condition of the loop currently says `num <= 10`, which is still valid when `num == 10`, and therefore results in the code also printing a `10`.

Comment: totally correct, for some code examples look at my answer :P

Answer (score 1):

You asked: 'I was trying to get my program to print the numbers from 1-9 and then stop at 10 – Neil Kumar'

You wanted this:

```
for(int num = 1; num < 10; num++){
System.out.println("num = " + num);
}
```

If you want to be exceptionally clever but not using functional jdk8 code:

```
for(int num = 1; num < 10; System.out.println("num = " + num++);
```